# XML encoding: mix attributes and elements

Tags: xml, go, marshalling

I have a question regarding marshalling Go XML: I get this:

```
<root abc="">
  <element></element>
</root>
```

but I'd like this:

```
<root>
  <element abc=""></element>
</root>
```

(the attribute `abc` is at the child element).

Is this (easily) possible?

My code:

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/xml"
    "fmt"
    "os"
)

type foo struct {
    XMLName xml.Name `xml:"root"`
    Abc     string   `xml:"abc,attr"`
    Element string   `xml:"element"`
}

func main() {
    f := foo{}
    a, err := xml.MarshalIndent(f, "", "  ")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        os.Exit(0)
    }
    fmt.Println(string(a))
}
```

Comment: https://play.golang.com/p/nIqXct02O5W

Comment: @mkopriva Thanks! I wonder if there is a way to use some operators in the `xml:"..."` tag, without using a nested struct.

Comment: AFAIK there isn't any way to move the attribute to a sibling field. The attribute field should be a field of the struct type whose resulting xml should have the xml attribute.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may define your struct like:

```
type foo struct {
    XMLName xml.Name `xml:"root"`
    Element struct{
        xml.Name `xml:"element"`
        Abc     string   `xml:"abc,attr"`
    }  
}
```